# NameVirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80 has no VirtualHosts

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, config

My server was working fine but something changed and I'm not sure what.

I'm getting the following error and am unable to get some of the subdomains.

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using     2001:.....:a669 for ServerName
[Sat Dec 14 21:20:36 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80 has no VirtualHosts
...
[Sat Dec 14 21:20:36 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80 has no VirtualHosts
Syntax OK
```

I've tried changing the ports.conf to Listen 80 and Listen 0.0.0.0:80  (see http://www.rackaid.com/resources/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-apache-server/ )

Here is one of my vhost files.

```
NameVirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
    ServerName www.domain.us
    ServerAlias domain.us
    ServerAdmin email@domain.us

    DocumentRoot /home/valid_domain_path/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/valid_domain_path/www>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www.domain.us.error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel info

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/www.domain.us.access.log combined
```

The 000-default is linked correctly.

Apache 2.2.22

Thanks,

Comment: have you configured all your virtualhosts under one vhost file ?

Comment: No they are separate files. I just changed around some names in the server's host file and everything seems to be working but I'm still getting the error on startup.

Comment: is it possible to post the other vhost config file details, only the vhost declaration following stanzas.NameVirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>

Comment: I did the others look the same except that the directories and server names are changed.

Comment: Are you sure you still have Apache 2.2.22? Lots of users have these problems now, after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10, which uses Apache2.4 instead...

Answer (score 10):

If my suspicions are right, and your system has recently been updated, you are now using Apache 2.4 instead of 2.2, just like many other users who just (got) moved to the new Ubuntu 13.10 version. (If you haven't changed to Apache 2.4 already, now is probably a good time to update your new *.conf files anyway.)

Here is a very good explanation about how to make named-based VirtualHosts work in Apache 2.4:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

In essence:

1. Don't use ANY "NameVirtualHost" entries from now on
2. Start all your VirtualHost entries like this `<VirtualHost *:80>`
3. Make sure to include exactly one ServerName in each VirtualHost entry, eg. `ServerName www.example.com`

In the end it should look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com 
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName other.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```